# Android: How to call and save userID as a session from SQLite database?

Tags: php, android, mysql, sqlite, session

In my application, I am trying to figure out how to save userID session and use it until the user closes the app.

I know in PHP you can just use the $_SESSION['userID'] = $user_id

I want to run a query something like this in Android SQLite

```
SELECT user_id, username, password
FROM users
**WHERE user_id = $_SESSION[user_id]**
```

This is from php, is there some way I can do this in android? I heard about shared preferences but I am not sure how it works?

Sorry, I just started learning about Android programming. I am a bit of a noob. I'll appreciate if you could help me out here.

**EDIT**: this userID is a column that I will be calling from SQLite database and saving it as a session when the user logs in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to declare global shared preferences:

```
SharedPreferences sp;
```

then in onCreate you delcare sp:

```
sp = getSharedPreferences("Session", 0); //"Session" is the file name it MUST be the same in all activities that require shared preferences.
```

So basically when the user login you check whether he is logged in, if it is true, then save his ID in the shared preferences using:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor e = sp.edit();
                e.putInt("ID", ID-Value-that-you-used-it-to-check-for-ID);
                e.commit();
```

and in the login class in onCreate, you add the second block to check whether the user is logged in and he has never logged out. and simply if he is then take him to the next activity.

```
if (cID != 0)
    {
        Intent iLogged = new Intent(this, The-Next-Class.class);
        finish();
        startActivity(iLogged);
    }
```

whenever you want to retrieve the value you just add...

```
int ID = sp.getInt("ID", 0);
```

and to log out the user and delete the session use the following:

```
sp.edit().clear().commit();
        Intent iLogout = new Intent(this,   Login.class);
        finish();
        startActivity(iLogout);
        break;
```

Edit 2:

What you got to do is...

1) retrieve the ID from the shared preferences.. now if the UserID column is int then use.

```
int ID = sp.getInt("ID", 0); // 0 is default value which means if couldn't find the value in the shared preferences file give it a value of 0.
```

2) you have to check, if the ID != 0 then pass the value to the query...

```
SELECT user_id, username, password
FROM users
WHERE user_id = ID
```

Comment: this userID is a column that I will be calling from SQLite database and saving it as a session when the user logs in. Do you know of how to go on about doing so?

Comment: check the edited part hope you got the idea, if not add the code to help you out more

Comment: how do I declare the user_id column of the user as an int from the sql database?

e.putInt("ID", not sure about this part);

see in the code above

Comment: user_id is the id that is autoincremented during the sign up page. so let's say: 

first registered user will have:
user_id : 1
username: rager
password: rager

second registered user will have:
user_id: 2
username: osama Espil
password: osama

and so on...

Then let's say user_id 1 (me) signs in via login activity and I would like to save user_id: 1 of this user in the shared preferences

Sorry if I wasn't clear enough before. Just to make sure if what you have described is doing what I have listed in this post above.

Comment: yes it works fine with you, i have modified my answer that suits your application. if you still find difficulties in adding the blocks provide your code and ill help you out

Comment: alright thanks. I'll try implementing it and ask if I get stuck. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: if you managed to implement it correctly, I hope you mark it as a right answer. best of luck

Comment: will do... don't worry :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing something similar in my android app using AppPreferences here is an example of a class i created to save an email to be used for later on in the app

```
public class AppPreferences {
public static final String ApplicationPreferences = "com.akada.danceworksonline.studio.MainActivity";
public String putEmail = "email";
private SharedPreferences sharedPrefs;
private SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor;

public AppPreferences(Context context) {

    this.sharedPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences(ApplicationPreferences,
            0);
    this.prefsEditor = sharedPrefs.edit();

}

public String getEmailPref() {
    return sharedPrefs.getString(putEmail, "");
}

public void saveEmail(String text) {
    prefsEditor.putString(putEmail, text);
    prefsEditor.commit();
}
```

and there wherever you make your call to the database have something along the lines of this .

```
AppPreferences _appPrefs = new AppPreferences(getApplicationContext());
```

then you can do something like _appPrefs.saveEmail(textviewEmail), or however you get your value.

Comment: thank you! I sort of got something what I wanted; however, how do I implement this with SQLite database?

Comment: I didn't use SQLite so you're on your own there. If I helped I'd appreciate an upvote :)

Comment: sorry I don't have enough reputation to add votes. :(